# Shallow copy of an object (class instance)

Tags: python-3.x, reference, python-3.6, shallow-copy

I am trying to understand shallow copies (references).

I have created a class that is supposed to make shallow copies of an instance if it already exists, but my code is making separate instances.

The intent here is that if I try to create a new object with the same x value as an existing object, I should create a reference to the existing object, not a new object.

```
from copy import copy


class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, x):
        seen = set()
        if x not in seen:
            self.x = x
            seen.add(x)
        else:
            self.x = copy(self.x)


f1 = Foo(10)
f2 = Foo(10)
f3 = Foo(10)

s = {f1, f2, f3}

for i in s:
    print(i)
```

This yields:

```
<__main__.Foo object at 0x03B21110>
<__main__.Foo object at 0x03AFB5B0>
<__main__.Foo object at 0x03B21150>
```

I should only have one object in the set (in this case) since all objects were created with the same x value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating a shallow copy of `Foo.x` but you're printing the Foo objects, not the references you created.  Try changing your print() statement to this:

```
print(hex(id(i.x)))
```

This would return a reference to a Foo object if you have already created one for that value of x:

```
seen = {}


class Foo:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x

    @classmethod
    def new(cls, x):
        if x not in seen:
            seen[x] = cls(x)
        return seen[x]


f1 = Foo.new(10)
f2 = Foo.new(10)
f3 = Foo.new(10)

s = {f1, f2, f3}

for i in s:
    print(i)
```

Comment: I see three identical values when I use your print statement - BUT - when I step through my code in the PyCharm debugger, I never see it hit the else clause. I do not think it is working correctly.

Comment: the scope of seen is ambiguous.   what happens if you declare seen in the global scope?

Comment: Do implement what I think you actually want, a singleton Foo(n) object, you probably want to add a static method for creating a new Foo object.  I'll update my answer with an example

Comment: AttributeError: 'Foo' object has no attribute 'x'

Comment: I updated my answer with an example using a classmethod to conditionally create new Foo objects.   It does raise the question, why not just use a dictionary by itself?